calculating large exponents in C++ and storing digits in vectors
how can I compute all the digits of some really large exponents in C++?
for example.
2^10^9 it will have around 3 * 10^8 digits how can i compute every digit and store it in an array?
successive multiplication by 2 will be really slow for this problem.
is there some dynamic programming approach?

see: What are the .... arbitrary-precision math libraries?

left-shift a multiprecision 2 by 10^9 bits. Or really just append 10^9 zero bits to a 1 bit. All the time will be spent converting to decimal. Maybe you'll figure out a pattern to the digits.

Are you sure you know what "dynamic programming" means? I don't think this is an example. Read the tag description.

Calculating 2^10^9 is not going to be slow, converting that number to decimal surely will be.

How to write it will depend on your performance target. In python, print(pow(2,1000000000)) would probably take weeks.

@SimonGoater Within 5 minutes it started output a large number, when doing: python -c "import sys; sys.set_int_max_str_digits(440000000); print(pow(2,1000000000))" on my Windows 11 system.  (I know the 440000000 is just a guess....!)

@SimonGoater: BTW when redirecting output to a file, the output will have a size of  301.029.998 bytes.

That was a rough estimate from the performance of print(pow(2,n)) for n=1000000. 5000000, and 10000000. I'm a noob with python. I get AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'set_int_max_str_digits'. Any ideas? Think it's because I'm on 3.8.10.

@SimonGoater: You are using Python2? (see: https://onecompiler.com/python2/42w9zzumd, which produces that result too )

That attribute was added 3.11 according to this https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html. Anyway, a good library function should be able to solve in minutes then.

Computing all the binary digits will be trivial, as others have noted (the value is simply represent as a binary 1 followed by a billion 0 bits). Representing that in memory (e.g.  all billion and one bits) will consume a potentially significant amount of memory.  Converting to another base (not a power of 2, e.g. to decimal in order to print it) will take time, and also memory, since that is done by repeated division by ten (binary 0b01010) which [also] nominally produces the decimal digits in reverse order (so must be output in reverse order, not the order they are computed).

And, BTW, this has nothing to do with dynamic programming.

comments here make use of base being 2, can we first be sure 2 is going to be base?

GMP functions mpz_ui_pow_ui and the gmp_printf family can do 2^10^9 in a few minutes.

Please clarify in which number system you want to store the result values, do you want the decimal digits or the binary digits? Also is the input representation always to the base of 2 or is the base a random number?

For any number conversion between different bases which are prime to each other, there is no repeatable bit pattern and thus you need to iterate over every digit. I doubt there is any other solution than the successive multiplication.
